# How to convert String to Json using Regex?

Tags: python, json, regex

I have been trying to figure out how to make string to a json using regex.

What I have tried to scrape is the value `items` and convert it to json:

```
{
  'submitId': 'commodity-show-submit',
  'params': [
    [
      'color',
      'COLOUR'
    ],
    [
      'items',
      'Select items'
    ]
  ],
  'items': {
    "48924": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 10"
      ]
    },
    "48925": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 10.5"
      ]
    },
    "48926": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 11"
      ]
    }
  },
  'pids': [
    48924,

  ],
  'items': [
    'Banana',
  ],
  'cartId': '.common-cart',
  'imgId': '',
  'onInvalid': function(){
    message("Please select a variant: %s.")
```

And I don't have big knowledge of regex but I tried to challange myself and I think I am totally out of the zone. It did only grab theh first object of items.

```
r"'items': (.+?)}"
```

---

Basically what I am trying to do is to convert this part to json

```
'items': {
    "48924": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 10"
      ]
    },
    "48925": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 10.5"
      ]
    },
    "48926": {
      "params": [
        "black",
        "US 11"
      ]
    }
  }
```

What would be the best way to be able to do that?

Comment: Is there a hard requirement to use regex? Why not using a JSON parser available?

Comment: Because I believe the JSON parser wouldn't work due to the end of the json where it ends with `'onInvalid': function(){
    message("Please select a variant: %s.")`. @SergioPulgarin

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)` seems to work even for objects with `functions` (because it's ignoring them).

Comment: @SergioPulgarin I believe that is for Javascript? I am using Python :)

Comment: So I think you have a problem at the source of the data. Can it be cleaned before reaching this point?

Comment: @SergioPulgarin the source data is what I am getting when I am scraping it. Unless you meant something else?

Comment: Use regex then to convert this pattern `function(){}` into `''`, then replace single quotes with double quotes, then it should work. (Remember function can take arguments and all the possible spacing combinations allowed).

Comment: @SergioPulgarin I have no idea how that would actually work, would you please give me an example?

Comment: Start by a simple test string with functions and see if you can come up with a regular expression that removes the function on all the valid forms they can appear (see `re.sub`).

Comment: Alright! Thanks :)

Comment: This one seems a good start: `"function\s*\(.*\)\s*{.*}"` and make sure to call `replace('\n', '')` on the string to remove newline characters. (This is a good resource when building regular expressions https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the use of Regex to clean up the string, then put the cleaned string into `json`. Remember that the JSON specification uses double quotes `"`.